# I'm recieving an error when using strptime, however it works when I manually input the date

Tags: python, datetime

Here is my code:

```
def updateUserDBDates():
    global userDB, currentDate, previousDate, changeInDate

    index = 0
    index2 = 0

    userDB[1] = datetime.strptime(userDB[0], "%d-%m-%Y")
    userDB[0] = datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), "%d-%m-%Y")
    userDB[0] = datetime.strptime(userDB[0], "%d-%m-%Y")

    saveData()

    currentDate = userDB[0]
    previousDate = userDB[1]
    changeInDate = currentDate - previousDate
```

This is the error I receive:

```
  File "/home/nathan/Documents/project001/programFiles/Project 001.py", line 170, in updateUserDBDates
    userDB[1] = datetime.strptime(userDB[0], "%d-%m-%Y")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2013-09-28 00:00:00' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
```

Should the code not make the time data `'28-09-2013'` (and therefore work)?

Comment: Do you know what those `%Y`, `%m` things mean in the format string?

Comment: If you have varying data, you may want to use `dateutil.parser.parse()` instead; [`python-dateutil()`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) is an external library.

Comment: You are reposting almost the same question without minutes without having read your error message and the documentation? next downvote.

Answer (score 2):

`strptime` has to *exactly* match; it cannot do partial matches. You should use

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-09-28 00:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 28, 0, 0)
```

Note that if you used `"%Y-%m-%d"`, instead of your incorrect `"%d-%m-%Y"`, you would have gotten a more informative error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  00:00:00
```

---

If you really want to only match the start you can use `re` to preprocess the data:

```
yyyymmdd = re.search('\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d', '2013-09-28 00:00:00').group()
datetime.datetime.strptime(yyyymmdd, "%Y-%m-%d")
#>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 28, 0, 0)
```

---

Alternatively if you want the day but know the whole format you can use the `date` method:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-09-28 12:04:43', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
#>>> datetime.date(2013, 9, 28)
```

Comment: AFAIK, `datetime` objects have `date()` method that creates new `date` object from given `datetime` object.

Comment: That's ace, TYVM. Updated.